# If $b$ is the largest square divisor of $a$ and $a^2|c$ then $a|b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think this is false, a counter example could be:
$c = 100,$
$b = 10,$
$a = 5$

But the book answer is true :( ! Did I misunderstand the problem or the book's answer was wrong?

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: Did you write what you mean for that counterexample? $a^2=16$ which doesn't divide 100. (Also, I think square divisor means, divisor that is a perfect square, so $b=10$ doesn't work either). Actually, I don't understand the statement of the theorem, what does $c$ have to do with anything?

Comment: Is the problem correctly stated? For instance, take $a=8$, $b=4$, and $c=64$. Then $a^2|c$, and $4$ is the largest square divisor of $8$, but $8\nmid 4$.

Comment: @yunone: Exactly. c needs some more information. If it is merely "there exists a c" then that hypothesis is meaningless since you can always pick $c=a^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With or without your edit, b does not divide a.  I suspect the question you want is

If b is the largest square divisor of c (not a) and a^2|c then a|b?

Then the answer would be true.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a counterexample:  $10$ is not a divisor of $4$ and $4^2$ does not divide $100$.  You must have at least one typo.

Perhaps you are trying to ask this:  if $b^2 | c$ and $b$ is the largest number with this property (NOTE NOT $b^2 | a$), and also $a^2|c$ then must $a|b$?

The answer to that would be yes, which you can prove by thinking about each prime that divides $a$ and showing it divides $b$ at least as many times.

Comment: @arron: You're right. I thought the book's answer was correct now. I was thinking 2^2 but then I took 4|10.